# Is John Hurt actually going to be the next Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

John Hurt is over 70 years old.  Even the first Doctor in the original series who looked like he was 200 was about 60 yrs old at the time.  To me it just wouldn't seem good for Clara who is about 30 to be traveling with a Doctor in which the actor is 73.

Comment: At this point in time any speculation on who the next Doctor will be is likely just that, speculation.

Comment: I don't see what their ages have to do with anything. Clara and the Doctor don't have a romantic relationship, so I don't think it would be weird for her to be traveling with him, regardless of the age of the body he is currently inhabiting. Is it weird that 30 year old Clara is currently traveling with 1000 year old Doctor? Nope.

Comment: OLD PEOPLE AND YOUNG PEOPLE CAN'T SPEND TIME TOGETHER?!?!?!?!? Jenna-Louise Coleman is 27, although I thought her character was meant to be younger than that.

Comment: This question, I think, *can* be answered legitimately, he is not. At 2013 ComiCon, after showing extensive footage of John Hurt as the "missing" Doctor, Moffet was very clear that the next Doctor had not yet been cast.

Comment: This question is now answerable and hence no longer "too localised", even if such a thing was still a valid close reason.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that John Hurt may feature in a spin-off or sub-plot focused on the time war between the Time Lords and the Daleks.

It might be that he is the version of the Doctor who destroyed the Daleks and the time lords in the [Time War](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Great_Time_War), and is burdened with having committed genocide and destroyed Gallifrey. After all, the time war has only ever been referenced and never actually shown in the current run of the show, or directly shown in the previous run of the show.

But--this is all guesswork and speculation since the show runners have not released any details, and judging from their record of secrecy surrounding the plot of upcoming seasons, we probably won't know John Hurt's role until the next season actually airs.

[edit]: Some limited information that seems to indicate that John Hurt plays The Doctor during the Time War in some footage from the 50th Anniversary Special shown at the 2013 San Diego Comicon:

> And then — what looks like the Time War, between the Daleks and the
>   Time Lords! Seriously. Daleks blowing up, flames everywhere,
>   everything going to Hell. And in the middle of all the carnage, John
>   Hurt as the non-Doctor, looking resolute. "Great men are forged in
>   fire," he says. And then something about being the man who lit the
>   flames.

Source: http://io9.com/the-doctor-who-50th-anniversary-trailer-is-an-amazing-t-860043589

Answer (score 2):

**No**

28th January 2017:

> Sir John Hurt's wife, Anwen, has led tributes to the veteran actor after he died at the age of 77.

[BBC obituary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-38778145)

Comment: RIP John Hurt :(

Comment: You might want to check the dates. This question was asked in 2013, shortly before the Day of the Doctor episode.

Comment: But, edited today by someone who obviously hadn't read the news...